# sap.ui.ux3.Shell doesn't show initial view

Tags: sapui5

While using sap.ui.ux3.Shell, i am not able to get the initial view but navigating to other views and coming back shows me the initial view.
Kindly help me set the Initial view as default/onload of the application my first view(myprofile) should be uploaded.

PFB my code:

**View.xml**

```
<ux3:Shell id="idMainShell" worksetItemSelected="handleTabSelect">

    <ux3:worksetItems>
        <ux3:NavigationItem key="wi_1" text="My Profile"></ux3:NavigationItem>
        <ux3:NavigationItem key="wi_2" text="Dashboard"></ux3:NavigationItem>
        <ux3:NavigationItem key="wi_3" text="Wallet"></ux3:NavigationItem>
        <ux3:NavigationItem key="wi_4" text="Admin"></ux3:NavigationItem>
    </ux3:worksetItems>
</ux3:Shell>
```

**MyController.js**

```js
onInit: function() { };

handleTabSelect : function(oEvent) {
  var sWSIKey = oEvent.mParameters.key;
  var oShell = oEvent.oSource;
  switch (sWSIKey) {
  case "wi_1":
//   prompt("Username :");
//   prompt("Password :");
   var oView = sap.ui.view({
    viewName : "exercise2_ewallet.tabs.myprofile",
    type : sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML
   });
   break;
  case "wi_2":
   var oView = sap.ui.view({
    viewName : "exercise2_ewallet.tabs.dashboard",
    type : sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML
   });
   break;
  case "wi_3":
   var oView = sap.ui.view({
    viewName : "exercise2_ewallet.tabs.wallet",
    type : sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML
   });
   break;
  case "wi_4":
   var oView = sap.ui.view({
    viewName : "exercise2_ewallet.tabs.admin",
    type : sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML
   });
   break; 
  default:
   var oView = new sap.ui.commons.TextView({
    text : "View is not available"
   })
  }

  oShell.setContent(oView);
 }
```

Regards,
Roshan.

Thanks in advance...I am new to sap ui5 so encountering these basic problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used the hook method,instead of that PFB the code modifications which helped me achieving my objective:

**XML View:**

```
<ux3:Shell id="idMainShell" worksetItemSelected="handleTabSelect">

    <ux3:worksetItems>  
        <ux3:NavigationItem key="exercise2_ewallet.tabs.myprofile" text="My Profile"></ux3:NavigationItem>
        <ux3:NavigationItem key="exercise2_ewallet.tabs.dashboard" text="Dashboard"></ux3:NavigationItem>
        <ux3:NavigationItem key="exercise2_ewallet.tabs.wallet"    text="Wallet"></ux3:NavigationItem>
        <ux3:NavigationItem key="exercise2_ewallet.tabs.admin"     text="Admin"></ux3:NavigationItem>
    </ux3:worksetItems>
</ux3:Shell>
```

**Controller.JS**

```js
onInit: function() {
  this._workItems = {};}

onAfterRendering: function() {
  this._workItems["exercise2_ewallet.tabs.myprofile"] = sap.ui.xmlview("exercise2_ewallet.tabs.myprofile");
  this.byId("idMainShell").setContent(this._workItems["exercise2_ewallet.tabs.myprofile"]); 
 },
```

This way if we set it to onAfterRendering method i am able to set the initial page to myProfile while using Shell ,when the application is getting uploaded.

Regards,
Roshan.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that content is empty after the initialization, because it's filled only when you click on a `NavigationItem`.
You have to assign the content of the first screen to the `content` aggregation of `ux3.shell`. This aggregation will be overwritten in your event handler.

If you want to do it programatically, you can call your event handler `handleTabSelect` manually during the first rendering of the screen (for example from `onInit` hook method). In this case, you have to construct the Event object manually.

It's much better idea to move the view selector logic into a separate function from event handler `handleTabSelect`; this new function accepts one parameter `sWSIKey`; if the parameter is empty (in the initialization phrase), you can set the default screen to the content area.